# Twitter & Facebook access to webView

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiwebview, twitter

I am making an iOS app in which users login to Facebook and Twitter through the iphone accounts.

However, once they are logged in, if I load a Webview with a url leading to Twitter or Facebook, the users are asked to Login into their account inside the webView.

My question is,
 What should I do in order once I have signed in into my Twitter and Facebook account through my app, open a webView with a twitter/facebook url without it asking the users to sign in again.

Im new to iOS Development, so I'am having quite a hard time understanding the logic of signing in to social networks etc.

Comment: Through which API you are loggin into the Facebook and Twitter ?

Comment: For the Twitter part I am using this example https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample , while for the Facebook part I am using the Facebook 3.5 SDK following this example https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

Comment: Okay then , they will surely ask you for login , if the url you are trying to open a URL in webview , as you have not logged in through webview.

Comment: But is there a possibility to login with the already logged in user. (The user that logged in through my app)

Comment: No. These are different ways to login and if you login through Facebook SDK , you will get the session for the current user. Then if you try to open url in webview , it wont have that session for the logged in User through SDK , So it again asks for login again.